# If I want to add 'period' in the database (one month), and would like to make calculations with the first day of the period. What would I have to do?

Tags: database, data, data-types

I have a question.

I want to add 'period' in the database. A period would always be 1 month. How Would I be able to make calculations with the period?

For example I want to calculate the following:

A = Last day of Current Period -  Last day of Previous Period

How would I be able to make the system understand what the last day of the period is? And the previous period?

That could be for example 28, 30 or 31. Could anyone please help me out.

In this case it would be:

31th of October - 30th of September

Thanks!

Comment: It's not clear what "A" is actually supposed to represent. If you just want "the last day of the month", most databases have a scalar function for that (e.g. in SQL Server it is `EOMONTH`). If you want "the number of days in the month", it is just the day number of the last day of the given month. Also, remember months are not just 28, 30, or 31 days long, but also sometimes 29 days.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! With 'A' I wanted to give an example that 'A' should represent the outcome of this calculation

Comment: Do you have some client program in mind where the calculation shall happen? Or do think of SQL queries which shall include these calculations?

Comment: @businessanalyst-junior-, yes but your whole question is unclear, and I was hoping you'd clarify exactly what you're struggling with. Do you have any experience as a programmer?

Answer (score 3):

Calculating anything involves behavior. Database tables store data, not behavior. When dealing with dates, choose a solution that properly models all of the crazy rules around dates. There is no way to store data that calculates something. Instead, store data that describes the period.

Your program can query the database for this information. Based on the type of period and duration, you would need to write programming code to calculate this. Programming languages have built-in library functions or data types to handle date calculations. For example, if implementing this in the .NET technology stack, the DateTime type should be used.

You could write stored procedures in the database to handle the date calculations, but only choose this option if the database vendor has a good set of library functions for calculating dates.

Answer (score 0):

Most modern SQL databases provide you with the functions for doing this. For example, with MS SQL Server, all you need for calculating what you asked for are the functions

- `YEAR`, `MONTH`, `DAY`, `DATEFROMPARTS`, `DATEADD` and `DATEDIFF`

(See https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_ref_sqlserver.asp  for a full reference or other databases).

Assumed you have a column `myDate` and want to calculate the value A from your question, this can be a little tricky with these functions. I would approach it this way:

- add one month to myDate: `DATEADD(month,1,mydate)`
- get the month and year from that, replace the day of the month by 1, and subtract one day:

  ```
   DATEADD(day,-1, DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(DATEADD(month,1,mydate)), MONTH(DATEADD(month,1,mydate)), 1))
  ```

This gives you the last day of the current month.

Now do the same for `DATEADD(month, -1, myDate)`, this gives you the last day of the previous period. Finally, use `DATEDIFF` to calculate the difference.

Of course, trying to cram all this stuff into one large SQL statement is not the best idea, hence you may consider to use a stored procedure where you can provide some variables for the intermediate values.

I am sure there is a simpler solution out there, but the approach above is almost straightforward and should not be to hard to understand.